# Как сделать чтоб в коде сумма чисел не повторялась?

Tags: python

Дана последовательность N целых положительных чисел. Необходимо определить количество пар элементов этой последовательности, сумма которых делится на m = 80 и при этом хотя бы один элемент из пары больше b = 50.

Дело в том, что код может считать и те суммы чисел, которые уже были.

```
f = open('####')
s = f.read().split()
count = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    for n in range(len(s)):
         a = int(s[i])
         if i != n:
             b = int(s[n])
             sum = a + b
             if((sum % 80 == 0) and (a > 50 or b > 50)):
                  count+=1
print(count)
f.close()
```

Comment: Опишите более связно проблему, что не так в этом алгоритме, и что требуется от него?

Comment: Пример: 120 и 80 дают сумму 200, также такую же суму дают числа 80 и 120, а еще 79 + 121. Мне нужно, чтоб он посчитал эту сумму не 3 раза, а вего лишь один. Надеюсь вы поняли

Comment: нет, мы не поняли. Что должно получиться в результате выполнения этого кода?

Comment: Извините, я задание забыл прикрепить

Comment: Ну, посчитать и поделить пополам. Ведь каждая пара анализируется 2 раза: как a и b, и как b и a.

Comment: Только вот определённая сумма может состоять не только из двух чисел.

Comment: пихать суммы в set и патом глянуть длинну множества

Comment: пара может состоять только из двух чисел!

Comment: Мне даны 10000 и 1 число, каждое надо с каждым перебрать.

Comment: `for n in range(i+1,len(s)):` - и тогда не будет повторений, если сами числа не повторяются во вводе

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло

Comment: А что-то не вижу в условии задачи, что суммы должны быть уникальными.

Comment: Судя по ответу они должны быть уникальными.

Comment: [Не вижу](https://inf-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=28130) этого. Более того, вижу, что даже не уникальные входные числа могут образовывать не уникальные пары.

Comment: могу ссылку на задачу отправить если нужно

Comment: @GrAnd Как раз по вашей ссылке видно, что пары должны быть уникальными (в в смысле элементов списка, а не значений). Там есть 40, 120, но нет 120, 40. А то, что 40, 120 присутствует дважды это потому что в списке 40 присутствует дважды.

Comment: @Эникейщик Я это и сказал. Если есть повторения на входе, то есть и повторения на выходе. Перевёртыши, естественно, не учитываются.

Answer (score 0):

Прямолинейный как доска алгоритм:

1. Считать сумму каждых двух элементов.
2. Если она кратна 80 и (Х или 80-x больше 50), то увеличиваем count на 1.
3. В конце разделить count на 2, т.к. каждая пара посчиталась дважды.

Comment: Откуда число 120?

Comment: число 120 из вашего комментария. Непонятно, что оно там делает, наверное, специально, чтобы других запутать.

Comment: Так я же пометил, что это только пример, чтоб объяснить ситуацию

Comment: плохо объяснил, потому что в том примере должно посчитаться 2, а не 1. Объяснять надо так, чтобы объяснение соответствовало задаче.